# Remove NULL values from ServiceStack dynamic result set

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to remove some weird NULL result from my ServiceStack dictionary query:

```
var results = Db.SqlList<Dictionary<string, object>>("SELECT * FROM TableName");
```

the results I get is:

```
[
   {
      "ID": 41,
      "IDLIC": 1,
      "FLGPREF": {
         "__type": "System.DBNull, mscorlib"
      },
      "PROT": {
         "__type": "System.DBNull, mscorlib"
      },
      "NOTE1": "just the note 1",
      "NOTE2": "just the note 2"
   }
]
```

I would like to remove the NULL FLGPREF and PROT fields from the output.
Is there a way to do it without using Dapper?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you've set `JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true` somewhere which is type type information is being serialized from your service response.

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = Db.SqlList<Dictionary<string, object>>("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE PROT IS NOT NULL OR FLGPREF IS NOT NULL");
```